# Geometric properties of fine moduli space of representations of a bound quiver

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory

We know that for a quiver without relations, if one has a fine moduli space $M$ of representations wrt a certain dimension vector and character, then $M$ is smooth and projective (a standard ref is King's paper). It seems this does not generalize to bound quivers except projectivity.

My question is: do we know any geometric properties(normality, smoothness, dimension of the space) for fine moduli space of a bound quiver? If not, is there any condition we can put on the quiver to imply some of the above properties?

Thanks!